# MacOS kernel panics when unmounting Time Machine disk images over SSHFS mount

Tags: time-machine, mount, kernel-panic

I made a simple Bash script to back up my Mac through Time Machine over network. It mounts a server through SSHFS using MacFUSE, mounts a HFS+ sparsebundle disk image inside that mount, and tells Time Machine to back up to it, unmounting them when it's done. It usually works just fine, but a kernel panic happens about once in every 6 or so times when it tries to unmount the sparsebundle disk image. The kernel panics seemed to happen both in MacOS Catalina and Big Sur. The same problem never changed even when I changed from a Macbook Air late 2015 to a 2020 MacBook Pro, so I believe the Mac hardware might be irrelevant.

Is there a way to tell if this is a problem relating to the Apple DiskImages driver, the MacFUSE kernel extension, or something different? Should I consult Apple or the maker of MacFUSE if there is no other way to correct this?

Here is the Kernel Panic backtrace:

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801ad85bc4): "wire_count == 0, m = 0xffffff8032fd02b0, obj = 0xffffff803d9b9d00\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.c:7572
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa090a739d0 : 0xffffff801acbab4d 
0xffffffa090a73a20 : 0xffffff801adfd7e3 
0xffffffa090a73a60 : 0xffffff801adede1a 
0xffffffa090a73ab0 : 0xffffff801ac5fa2f 
0xffffffa090a73ad0 : 0xffffff801acba3ed 
0xffffffa090a73bf0 : 0xffffff801acba6d8 
0xffffffa090a73c60 : 0xffffff801b4bef9a 
0xffffffa090a73cd0 : 0xffffff801ad85bc4 
0xffffffa090a73e20 : 0xffffff801b42ad4f 
0xffffffa090a73e70 : 0xffffff801d2969c1 
0xffffffa090a73e90 : 0xffffff801d2960aa 
0xffffffa090a73eb0 : 0xffffff801d296000 
0xffffffa090a73ed0 : 0xffffff801b3fc9f7 
0xffffffa090a73ef0 : 0xffffff801b3f9a7d 
0xffffffa090a73f30 : 0xffffff801b41691e 
0xffffffa090a73f70 : 0xffffff801b415f06 
0xffffffa090a73fa0 : 0xffffff801ac5f13e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.DiskImages(493.0)[11E51AF9-6467-39AC-89A2-A62CE763F298]@0xffffff801d295000->0xffffff801d2a0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[B5300908-BF34-3D47-8776-FB154A6DEE4C]@0xffffff801d73f000->0xffffff801d750fff

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: -v chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20D74

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C86236B2-4976-3542-80CA-74A6B8B4BA03
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001aa00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff801ac00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001aa10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff801ac10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801ab00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,3 (Mac-E7203C0F68AA0004)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11092066957957
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00000a1692b5fd2e
  Sleep   : 0x00000877d70daad5 0x00000bfb283e2420 0x000008693a36c209
  Wake    : 0x00000877e168dd7b 0x00000c4e1fdaf8c6 0x00000877e012bf29
last started kext at 11091852477214: >!AXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff801c467000, size 12288)
last stopped kext at 10623433685325: >!AXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff801c467000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
io.macfuse.filesystems.macfuse  2053.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.18
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.18
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4030.5
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.3d9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ABridgeAudio!C    100.2
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   100.2
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.431
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.apfs   1677.81.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!A!BModule 1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  223
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4030.5
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.3d9
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
|IOAVB!F    930.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  585
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOGraphics!F   585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    8.0.3d9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.3d9
>!AConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1
>!A!BDebug  1
>!A!BDebugService   1
>!AConvergedPCI 1
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AMultiFunctionManagerMac  1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.3d9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.3d9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801ad85bc4): "wire_count == 0, m = 0xffffff8032fd02b0, obj = 0xffffff803d9b9d00\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.c:7572
```

This panic signature is identical to one that I've encountered myself with sudden removal of a disk image backing store. It's a bug in the macOS disk image driver, not MacFUSE (MacFUSE wasn't installed on my machine). You should [report the panic to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). Giving them readily reproducible steps will be key to fixing the issue.